# Is such a database normalized?

Tags: database

Consider such a database

Developer table

```
+--------------+------+---------+
| developer_id | name | revenue |
+--------------+------+---------+
| 1            | John | 154,01  |
+--------------+------+---------+
```

Application table

```
+--------------+------------------+-------+-------------+
| developer_id | application_name | price | sold_copies |
+--------------+------------------+-------+-------------+
| 1            | photo_app_1      | 0,79  | 123         |
+--------------+------------------+-------+-------------+
| 2            | photo_app_2      | 1,99  | 34          |
+--------------+------------------+-------+-------------+
```

So the database:

- has a relation one developer to many applications
- revenue of developer is derived from summing `price * sold_copies` of all applications

Is this database normalized? If not, which normal form does it violate?

Comment: Revenue is a dynamic entity, so it should be just calculated at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion it is violating the second NF:

If you update the number of copies sold, then you have to update the revenue of all developers involved. Now imagine you where to update the price..

Let's keep the `Developer` table as it is.

Reduce the `Application`

```
id | application_name 
---+------------------
 1 | photo_app_1
```

Create a reference table for Application-Developer

```
 application_id  |  developer_id
-----------------+---------------
              1  |           1
              1  |           2
```

That's how there can be multiple developers involved in developing the same application.
Now the price: Normally you would hold a receipt for each sold copy (which is interesting for accounting but also when the price changes) and you need a table for the application price itself.

```
 application_id  | price  | date
-----------------+--------+-----------
              1  |   0.79 | 2020-05-12
              1  |   0.55 | 2020-05-13
```

Receipt table:

```
 id |   date     | application | copies
----+------------+-------------+-------
 1  | 2020-05-12 |           1 |      1
 2  | 2020-05-13 |           1 |      1
```

With these tables you can calculate the total revenue for the application 1: Look up all sales for application 1, check the prices for each sold copy at a specific date and calculate how much every developer of that application earned.

Then finally, you can calculate how much a developer earned in total with all his applications.

The second NF:

"A relation is in second normal form if it is in 1NF and every non key attribute is fully functionally dependent on the primary key." ([--> read more here](http://www.gitta.info/LogicModelin/en/html/DataConsiten_Norm2NF.html))
Meaning, any "functional" value in your database should have it's own id (it's own table).

That's why we create a table for the prices of each application (at a specific date), a table for each sale of any application and a table for each developer involved in the application development.

Sorry if I can't explain it better. It has been quite a while that I learned the exact specifications of the NFs ;)

Comment: by the way: the acutal revenue shouldn't be stored in any table - because it would have to be updated all the time and it really depends only on the number of sold copies and the price. It would be better to create a view for that.

Comment: I agree, but there are some cases where executing that view could be extremely costly... particularly if the developer's total revenue needs to be displayed on hundreds of selects and only rarely changes. (e.g. a user's point score on an upvoting site). In those cases I sometimes use triggers to recalculate the user's sums when something in a `units` type of table changes. Typically I put the sums into a tracking table that gets reconciled just in case with a nightly cron job that runs the whole view.

Comment: good point!  Your trigger could update the "current month's revenue" (as it is likely to change often) while the revenue of the last month won't normally change, in which case it is best to put it in a dedicated table. In any case the number of reads/writes should be balanced and the DB design adapted to the needs. That's where the NFs cannot always be applied one to one.